# How can i fix npm proxy erorr?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install

I want install a npm package.json file for manage gulp tasks and i did not set any proxy but i have this error :

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-26-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.12.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:34663
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
npm ERR!  { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:34663
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '127.0.0.1',
npm ERR!   port: 34663,
npm ERR!   parent: 'website' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Consider, i set proxy null and registry but yet i have this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED:** Set all proxy configuration to `null`, both `http` and `https` proxy

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set https-proxy null
npm config set http-proxy null
```

and also set the registry

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: i using ubuntu and i have not any proxy ip and server. at morning this worked good but now have this error ....